# Exception handling in RESTful services in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jax-rs

I have been working in JAVA and developing Restful services from quite a long time now. I just finished developing the services and now testing phase is progress, that is where issues arises.

Whats happening exactly is, take this service for example:

```
    location = locationFacadeREST.findBy("findByP852", item[i]).get(0); 
    System.out.println(location);
```

The statement will return the 'item' from Location table which is in my database, it will return the perfect data if the itemis available in database, but throws internal server exception if not in database.

Handled that with try catch like this:

```
try{               
    location = locationFacadeREST.findBy("findByP852", item[i]).get(0); 
       }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
           output = "Invalid Accession No.";
           return output;               
       }
```

But i want to implement this in more than 100 files. 
Is the any way to do it once and call the try catch block whenever i need to handle the exception.

And also please tell if there is any way to return the catch block in xml format.

Comment: Write an interceptor. How, depends on the technology you're using. Your question is too vague.

Comment: Consider throwing a 404 Not Found error if the item doesn't exist in the database. It'll make exception handling easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but i'll try to help. (what frameworks u are using, why not using try catch blocks or some native interceptor). Take a look at this implementation of global exception handler by using controller advice if you are using spring framework. That should work;

```
@Slf4j
public abstract class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(WebRequest request, String message, int httpStatusCode)
            throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        String exceptionMessage = "Exception occured while system is running.";
        if (message != null)
        {
            exceptionMessage = message;
        }
        ErrorResource error = new ErrorResource(correlationId, exceptionMessage);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpStatus annotation = HttpStatus.valueOf(httpStatusCode);
        log.error(
                "Exception message = {} and Http Status code = {}",
                exceptionMessage,
                httpStatusCode);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, headers, annotation);
    }
}
```

But this class needed to call from @ControllerAdvice class.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllException(WebRequest request, Exception ex) {
    return handleException(request, ex.getMessage(), HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use [@RestControllerAdvice](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-mvc/use-restcontrolleradvice-new-features-spring-framework-4-3) to handle exception globally from `Controller` layer**

Just need to implement your expected exception's handler methods.

You can find the detail exception handling post [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#global-exception-handling)